# Setting up android Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create a custom toolbar as such

[image]

But I can't figure out how to edit the font, font size of both the title and the menu item ("DONE"). I can of course just put another view inside the toolbar view, but it doesn't seem proper as you lose access to the Toolbar methods.

min sdk version 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below method you can change `ToolBar` title font,

```
public static void changeToolbarFont(Context context, Toolbar toolbar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            Typeface titleFont = Typeface.
                    createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getResources().getString(R.string.font_name));
            if (tv.getText().equals(toolbar.getTitle())) {
                tv.setTypeface(titleFont);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @John, Using XML you have to use layout in `ToolBar`, there is no any method available for change font of `ToolBar` title.

Comment: ah ok, thanks! I guess I will have to build a class around Toolbar to eliminate boiler plate code.